# Submitting a dynamic number of rows from html form/table to MySQL using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So I've written the following with help from the folks on stack overflow.  The goal it to take a dynamic number of rows with 4 values and insert all of the rows into a mysql table via a single submit button.

The below code works, but only inserts the last row. Any help is appreciated thanks! -Todd

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('FIRST').deleteRow(i);
}


function insRow()
{
    console.log( 'hi');
    var x=document.getElementById('FIRST');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';
    var inp3 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
     inp3.id += len;
    inp3.value = '';
    var inp4 = new_row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
     inp4.id += len;
    inp4.value = '';
    x.appendChild( new_row );

} </script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="insertform.php" method = "post">
<table id="FIRST" border="1">
        <tr>
   <td>Line</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Selector</td>
            <td>Start Frequency</td>
            <td>Stop Frequency</td>
            <!--<td>Delete?</td>
            <td>Add Rows?</td> -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
            <td><input  type="number"  name = "Value1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" list="Selector" name="Selector" />
             <datalist id="Selector" >
             <option value=">">
             <option value="<">
             <option value="=">
             </datalist>
             </td>
            <td><input  type="number"  name="StartFreq"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="StopFreq"/></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <td><input type="button" id="addmoreFIRSTbutton" value="Add More Lines" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
    <input type = "submit" name ="submit">
</form>



<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mellow";
$dbname = "yellow";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}



$sql = "INSERT INTO FIRST ( Value, Selector, StartFreq, StopFreq)
VALUES ('$_POST[Value1]','$_POST[Selector]','$_POST[StartFreq]','$_POST[StopFreq]')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I've added the following to the query and added [] as suggested but I still need help converting the array to a usable PHP/ SQL statement.

See below

```html
 if($_POST[submit])
    {
     foreach ($_POST['Line'] as $key => $value)
        {
            $Line = $_POST["Line"][$key];
            $Value = $_POST["Value"][$key];
            $Selector = $_POST["Selector"][$key];
            $StartFreq = $_POST["StartFreq"][$key];
            $StopFreq = $_POST["StopFreq"][$key];

            $sql = mysql_query("insert into FIRST values ('$Line', '$Value','$Selector', '$StartFreq', '$StopFreq')");
        }

    }
```

Comment: What I usually do in this case is give in the name of inputs like this: `Value1[] Selector[] StartFreq[] StopFreq[]` and take the POST as an array in a loop

Comment: did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

As Charles said, put [] at the end of each input field name so that your php code on the back end will treat them as arrays. Then, in your php code,  use  a foreach loop to iterate over the arrays. Inside the foreach loop, dynamically construct your SQL INSERT statements and execute them,  one per row. . That's the way I've always done it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!    I have added the [] but i'm not sure how to do the foreach loop to dynamically create the SQL.  Can you help?  I get Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/matech/draw/form/insertform2.php on line 89

Comment: I'm still getting the array conversion message using the following:  Please help  //<?php
//    if($_POST[submit])
//    {
//     foreach ($_POST['Line'] as $key => $value)
//        {
//            $Line = $_POST["Line"][$key];
//            $Value = $_POST["Value1"][$key];
//            $Selector = $_POST["Selector"][$key];
//            $StartFreq = $_POST["StartFreq"][$key];
//            $StopFreq = $_POST["StopFreq"][$key];
//
//            $sql = mysql_query("insert into FIRST values ('$Line', '$Value','$Selector', '$StartFreq', '$StopFreq')");
//        }
//
//    }
//?>

Comment: Try $line = $_POST['Line']; foreach($line as $key =>$value){...do something here...}

Comment: Try echoing out your $_POST array on the backend to see what you actually are sending when your form is submitted.